# File does not get stored (mounted) if processing of versions fails

Tags: carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4.2, fog

I upgraded carrierwave from 0.11.0 to 1.2.3 and realised that a, for me crucial, behaviour has changed and broke my logic. Here is the example of my uploader.

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :fog

  version :thumb do
    process :convert => :jpg

    def default_url
      '/assets/document_thumb.png'
    end
  end

end
```

And the model that it's mounted too:

```
class Material < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :file

  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader, validate_processing: false

  before_create :create_file_hash

  def create_file_hash
    self.hash_digest = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(file.read)
  end

end
```

In the old carrierwave, even if the version processing (e.g. in this case the convert) failed the main version of the file would still be uploaded and stored. However, now in cases when processing fails (not always, but I can't do conditional processing as my case is more complex then here illustrated) nothing gets stored. The `file` attribute remains an empty (blank) uploader and nothing is uploaded to the fog storage.

**Any idea on how to get back the old behaviour?**

In other words, how to ignore any errors with processing of versions. Or not trigger processing of versions in the `after_cache` callback but rather some later time down the line?

I think I've tracked down this issue to the following change in [`Mounter#cache`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb#L42) method:

```
def cache(new_files)
  return if not new_files or new_files == ""
  @uploaders = new_files.map do |new_file|
    uploader = blank_uploader
    uploader.cache!(new_file)
    uploader
  end

  @integrity_error = nil
  @processing_error = nil
rescue CarrierWave::IntegrityError => e
  @integrity_error = e
  raise e unless option(:ignore_integrity_errors)
rescue CarrierWave::ProcessingError => e
  @processing_error = e
  raise e unless option(:ignore_processing_errors)
end
```

Which used to just do the `uploader.cache!(new_file)` directly (not in map) and then `uploader` got updated along the way and returned to the model when needed. However, now the processing error causes the map block to exit and `@uploaders` array never gets updated with the uploader that worked (i.e. for the original file).

Comment: Forgot to include `validate_processing: false` option that I indeed have on the mounter. And that one works in the sense that the model validation doesn't fail and the model does get saved. Just without the uploader.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be overriding the `cache!` method in you uploader instead:

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def cache!(*)
    super
  rescue CarrierWave::ProcessingError => e
    Rails.logger.debug "FileUploader: Error creating thumbnail: #{e}"
    nil
  end
  ...
end
```

That way, it works for every model

Answer (score 0):

Half a day of effort later here is the solution I've come up with that doesn't involve monkey patching carrierwave.

```
class Material < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :file

  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader, validate_processing: false      

  #----> This is to manually trigger thumbnail creation <----
  before_create :create_thumbnail

  def create_thumbnail
    file.thumb.cache!(file.file)
  rescue CarrierWave::ProcessingError => e
    Rails.logger.debug "FileUploader: Error creating thumbnail: #{e}"
  end

  # rest of the model code
end
```

So here we have `create_thumbnail` method triggered in `before_create` callback that manually calls the `cache!` method on the `thumb` uploader. The `file.file` is at this moment (i.e. before create, so before the file has been uploaded to the storage) pointing to the temporary cached file. Which is exactly what we want (we don't want to re-download the file from the storage just to create thumbnails.

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :fog

  #----> Add the if condition to versions <----
  version :thumb, if: :has_versions? do
    process :convert => :jpg

    #----> This is needed to trigger processing later <----
    after :cache, :process!

    def default_url
      '/assets/document_thumb.png'
    end
  end

  #---> This is to avoid versions before the main version is fully processed and cached <---
  def has_versions?
    !(model.new_record? && model[:file].nil?)
  end

end
```

Now this is the tricky party. We need to initially disable the version creations and for that reason we have the `has_versions?` method that checks if the file is a new record. Now that check is not enough, because in our `before_create` callback the model is still new record (i.e. it hasn't yet been persisted).

However, what's the difference between the first time the uploader tries to create the versions (and which, if it fails, prevents original file from caching as described in the question) and the moment we call it in our `before_create` callback is that in the second case the `file` attribute of the model will be set.

Be careful, however, because you cannot do `model.file` since that points to the uploader (and if called here where I'm calling it it would actually cause a stack overflow). You need to access it as `model[:file]`.

The final trick is that for some reason just calling `cache!` in the model would not actually trigger the processing. The processing was supposed to be triggered during the initial run (which we prevented for other versions) and since the original file is cached, carrierwave expects the versions are as well, so they don't need processing. But adding the `after :cache, :process!` ensures that it's triggered.

Don't know if anybody will find this useful or if I've gone about the problem the wrong way.

Either way, I'd love to hear comments.

Happy I made it work for my case and that I can continue using latest gem version.

Comment: Given the amount of complexity in this solution + the fact that it is still relying on `cache!` method, I prefer the monkey patch, as it is straight forward and short. This solution is cleaner "On paper" but the complexity is way higher and it is harder to explain (as seen by the comment amount)